# Difference between Content Provider and Stub Content Provider in android

Tags: android

What are the key differences between content provider and stub content provider in android ? I got this issue while going through running a sync adapter: https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/running-sync-adapter.html

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-stub-provider.html#CreateProvider

Answer (score 1):

Android sync adapter framework checks to see if there is a content provider in your app or not. If there is no content provider in your app, your sync adapter will not function.

If you don't use content provide to store data locally, you must provide stub content provider in order to make your sync adapter work.

Stub content provider is just a dummy implementation of content provider and it does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

When working with the **sync adapter framework** you can also create a stub content provider as an alternative.

So first thing is to **understand Sync Adapter framework**.

The sync adapter component in your app encapsulates the code for the tasks that transfer data between the device and a server.

**Creating a Stub Content Provider**

The sync adapter framework is designed to work with device data managed by the flexible and highly secure content provider framework. For this reason, the sync adapter framework expects that an app that uses the framework has already defined a content provider for its local data. If the sync adapter framework tries to run your sync adapter, and your app doesn't have a content provider, your sync adapter crashes.